# How to Configure Spring Cloud StreamBridge to produce Avro?

Tags: spring, dynamic, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-platform

So I am trying to use StreamBridge to dynamically send messages to different topics. I am successful in doing so if my output is a **Message< String>**, but not **Message< GenericRecord>**

Code example:

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
public void process(@Payload GenericRecord messageValue,
                    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) GenericRecord messageKey,
                    @Header("Type") String type) {
    log.info("Processing Event --> " + messageValue);

    // Code...

    // convert to Message<GenericRecord>
    Message<GenericRecord> message = ...

    streamBridge.send(type, message);

    log.info("Processed Event --> " + messageValue);
}
```

The error I get is `Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not write JSON: Not a map:` which I am guessing is because streamBridge acceptedOutputTypes = application/json

```
2020-06-28 04:42:55.670  INFO 54347 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.f.c.c.SimpleFunctionRegistry       : Looking up function 'streamBridge' with acceptedOutputTypes: [application/json]
```

I tried modify accepted output type to be avro by setting the following in my properties, which did not work.

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=streamBridge
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.streamBridge-out-0.content-type=application/*+avro
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.streamBridge-out-0.producer.use-native-encoding=true
```

Any ideas on how to configure StreamBridge to be avro?

edit: I also tried `streamBridge.send(type, message, MimeType.valueOf("application/*+avro"))` but that also had a conversion error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get StreamBridge to work dynamically so I switched to using Function:

```
@Bean
public Function<Message<GenericRecord>, Message<GenericRecord>> process() {
    return message -> {

        // Code...

        String topic = message.getHeaders().get("type");

        // convert to Message<GenericRecord>
        Message<GenericRecord> message = MessageBuilder...
            .setHeader("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", topic)
            .build();
        

        return outgoingMessage;
    };
}
```

Properties file is:

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=process
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-in-0.destination=${consumer_topic}
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-in-0.group=${spring.application.name}

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-out-0.content-type=application/*+avro
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-out-0.producer.use-native-encoding=true
```

Edit: Streambridge got fixed to support this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2007

Comment: Hi, there was a slight issue with the `StreamBridge` API when native encoding was enabled. This is addressed in the latest snapshots. Please see this sample for some examples of using `StreamBridge` with avro and native encoding: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/streambridge-samples/stream-bridge-avro

Comment: @sobychacko - I was able to get it working using an AVRO object like in your example. But when I tried Message<Sensor> I get the following error `Unsupported Avro type. Supported types are null, Boolean, Integer, Long, Float, Double, String, byte[] and IndexedRecord`. I also tried Message<GenericRecord>>. Being able to pass a Message object is useful so that we can pass custom headers and key.

Comment: @sobychacko - so in your code instead of just having `skipConversion ? v -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(v).build()` - can I pass the Message instead of StreamBridge building the message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to the the `useNativeEncoding` producer property to use a custom serializer.

Comment: I tried doing that with this `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.streamBridge-out-0.producer.use-native-encoding=true` but that did not work.