# Spring Cloud Stream Application Exits Before Supplier Finishes

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, reactor

I have a "task" application that is short lived and produces messages to Kafka based on statuses from a database. I'm using spring cloud stream to produce the messages using the below format of my application. I followed this format from the [Spring Cloud Stream documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_suppliers_sources) to send arbitrary data to the output binding.

```
private EmitterProcessor<Message<GenericRecord>> processor;
```

```
@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments arg0) {
    // ... create Message<GenericRecord> producerRecord
    this.processor.onNext(producerRecord);
}
```

```
@Bean
public Supplier<Flux<Message<GenericRecord>>> supplier() {
    return () -> this.processor;
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    ctx.close();
}
```

The application runs, creates the records, runs onNext(), and then exits. I then look to see if any messages have been published but there are none on the topic. I then added a `Thread.sleep(10000)` after each message is produced and the messages end up on the topic.

After looking at the documentation for Reactor I didn't seen any clear ways to accomplish this. Is there a way to wait for the EmitterProcessor to finish publishing the messages before the Spring application exits?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific reason to use the `EmittorProcessor`? I think this use-case can be solved by using `StreamBridge`. For e.g.

```
@Autowired StreamBridge streamBridge;


@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments arg0) {
    // ... create Message<GenericRecord> producerRecord
    this.streamBridge.send("process-out-0", producerRecord);
}
```

Then provide configuration for: `spring.cloud.stream.source: process`
You can find more details on `StreamBridge` in the ref docs.

Comment: I've attempted using StreamBridge but ran into problems using Avro and it. The application sends messages to a number of dynamic destinations and we do the Avro conversion ourselves when building the message. The StreamBridge using the converter with ContentType wouldn't let us send already valid Avro objects and would throw an error.

Comment: Feel free to share a small sample application where this happens?

Comment: I don't currently have an implementation using StreamBridge but this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641008/how-to-configure-spring-cloud-streambridge-to-produce-avro/62658779#62658779) experiences the same problem.

Comment: Hi, there was a slight issue with the StreamBridge API when native encoding was enabled. This is addressed in the latest snapshots. Please see this sample for some examples of using StreamBridge with avro and native encoding: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/streambridge-samples/stream-bridge-avro